# iTerm2 : Prevent lines from vim from going into scroll back

Tags: iterm

I was wondering how I can prevent iTerm2 from saving the output from a vim sessions into the scroll back history?  This isn't a feature when you are editing confidential files.

Answer (score 9):

Evidently I have the option Preferences-> Profile-> "Save lines to scrollback in alternate screen mode" checked.  Unchecking this feature seems to have stopped this behavior.

Comment: Glad I found this answer! I was experimenting with every single vim setting to stop this behavior until I realize this could be a terminal specific bug/feature .. Now vim is not leaving traces, overwriting command histories..